Merge table rows that are referenced as foreign keys in other tables
I have a table companies in which there are some duplicated rows I found with a simple GROUP BY name.
This companies table has a PRIMARY KEY id which is referenced in several other tables, under the name company_id, which I also found with a query on the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.
Now my requirement: Merge the two companies into one, meaning update all the referenced company_id to reference the first id of the two, then delete the second company
All the FOREIGN KEYS are already declared with ON UPDATE CASCADE clause but I'm not sure if there's a smart way of accomplishing the final result without manually updating all the referenced FOREIGN KEYS
My intuition was to

create a new temporary field mark_to_delete and set this = 1 on all the duplicated companies I want to delete
use FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 to avoid errors while updating a company.ID to an existing one
Delete companies that are mark_to_delete=1
Turn back on FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1

Clearly my biggest doubt is on how FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS works, I've tried reading the docs and searching for my specific case, but I can't understand if the ON UPDATE CASCADE will work or not.
Worst case scenario I think would be to list all the referenced company ID's, run updates on the tables with a referenced ID setting it to the "healthy" company, and then delete the duplicated company.

UPDATE slave
  JOIN main m1 USING (main_id)
  JOIN ( SELECT MIN(main_id) main_id, main_name
         FROM main m2
         GROUP BY 2
         ) m3 USING (main_name)
SET slave.main_id = m3.main_id;

The duplicates in the sample are the rows in main table with the same main_name value. So the subquery selects minimal main_id for all duplicates, and all references are replaced with this value.
Complete sample fiddle

Thanks this is a cool approach, if I understand correctly it will need to be repeated for each slave table that might have a reference to the main table. Meaning if I have 5 tables which contain a FOREIGN KEY referencing the company.ID I'll have to do this once for each table

@GiLA3 Yes, I recommend to perform this for each slave table separately. And the last DELETE which removes unused rows must have according WHERE NOT EXISTS conditions. Or you may set ON DELETE RESTRICT for each FK definition and use simple DELETE IGNORE FROM main;. https://dbfiddle.uk/yDGqPK1B

You don't need to change FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS and you don't need to think about ON UPDATE CASCADE.
What you call the "worst case scenario" is actually easier.

Identify duplicate companies. Say companies with id 1, 2, 14, 39 are duplicates of each other.

Pick one to use as the canonical row for that given company. Let's say it's 1.

Update any references in child tables to the other duplicate company ids:
UPDATE other_table SET company_id = 1
WHERE company_id IN (2, 14, 39);

This does not require changing FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, because the company_id references satisfy the constraint before and after the UPDATE.
This does not incur ON UPDATE CASCADE. Cascading is for when you update the referenced primary key, but you aren't doing that. You're changing the foreign keys in child table(s).

Repeat for any other tables that reference companies.

Once the duplicate rows in companies have no references in child tables, you are free to delete them.
DELETE FROM companies WHERE id IN (2, 14, 39);



I recommend double-checking all the other columns of companies before choosing the canonical row. Any of them could have useful data (e.g. current phone number), and you'd have to read them and merge manually.

This is what I had in my mind as the worst case scenario. I said worst case because I have about 60 duplicates (about 130 records, some are duplicates of 2, others of 3). The time consuming part is that I have about 10 tables where I might or might not have a reference to the main company table. I'll sure consider this approach tho, thanks for breaking it down in a more structured way.

Yes, data cleanup tasks can be time-consuming. They often need case-by-case attention because you have to examine each set of duplicates to decide which row is the best choice to keep. There's no way around that. It should only take a couple of hours to do the quantity you describe.
